Not charging on fedora 40 workstation
I just Installed Fedora 40 on my laptop (Lenovo ideapad gaming 3) and for some reason my battery is not charging it says “Not charging” on the settings. I am sure it is not a hardware problem because i have windows 11 installed on a different hard drive and i don’t have any problem on windows 11. Any possible fix?
Thx :)

stupid question from my side: and it's really not charging, or is just the display wrong?
